# Can I use GA4 for C++/Qt Desktop Application?

Tags: c++, firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-sdk

I have a C++/Qt Desktop application that runs on Linux. As far as I know, Firebase can not be used for desktop applications. I would like to utilize GA4 for UX Analytics by collecting similar events as Firebase does on Android/iOS. I would appreciate any tips about the feasibility of this idea and where to start.

I have seen that Firebase is available for C++ but only on Android/iOS. Is it possible to port it for Linux and utilize it to collect events? (at least partially)

If the above idea is not possible, Can I use my custom software to collect events to form a CSV and then import it to GA4? I have searched for sample event datasets online but unfortunately, I could not find something available. (Sample projects of Google do not provide me raw data).

Answer (score 1):

"If the above idea is not possible, Can I use my custom software to collect events to form a CSV and then import it to GA4?"

You are correct that the Firebase [C++ SDK desktop support is a beta feature and not for publicly shipping code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup?#libraries-desktop) but as you mentioned there are ways to import events from **trusted** internet-connected devices but this comes with some caveats.

While not exactly what you are looking for, the [GA4 Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4) allows you to complement a mobile app or website with information from other online connected devices. One way you could use this would be to have users register via a website or a mobile app, have them then sign in on the desktop version and [retrieve some necessary API secrets](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9814495?sjid=16492617813506765491-NA) onto a server you are running in a trusted environment. From there you have to **maintain authentication and the integrity of the passed-in events yourself** in your app and its connection to your server as Desktop does not have a GA4 client.

There are other caveats here in that events generated by the GA4 SDK and Measurements Protocol differ in automatically collected fields and how/when they are processed. If a feature requires Firebase client functionality during event generation or reporting it will not be available to events generated via the Measurement protocol.